# Enabling DSA key authentification for SFTP while still keeping password login as optional (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: linux, authentication, ubuntu-12.04, sftp, dsa

I have a server running Ubuntu 12.04 Server. I want to be able to use SFTP on the command line with a DSA key, so I don't have to type the password into the terminal. Is this possible to do on the **same** server... i.e I want to SFTP to localhost (to test some PHP code before running it live). But I still want to allow password login by other clients if they want to. I don't want the certificate to be **forced**, but I don't want it to ask for the password if the certificate is passed or whatever.

I have the following options enabled in ssh_config:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

The following files with shown permissions are in /root/.ssh/

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  668 Apr 10 11:06 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 root root  668 Apr 10 11:03 id_dsa
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  608 Apr 10 11:03 id_dsa.pub
```

I copied the key into authorized keys with:

```
cat /root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And when I cat authorized keys, it has added the key.

So, when I try to connect to sftp with `sftp -v root@testserver` (just locally, again, for testing some code but that's irrelevant), I still get the password prompt. Here's a section of the verbose output:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@testserver's password:
```

Have I missed something obvious? Or will it not work connecting locally?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The permissions in the `/root/.ssh` directory are wrong if `StrictModes yes` is set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. 
You can check if this is the case by enabling `LogLevel DEBUG`, restarting the server and watching the logs (`/var/log/auth.log` for Ubuntu, if you have not changed the stock syslog configuration)

Correct them issuing:

`chmod -R go= /root/.ssh`

and try again.

Having both `PubKeyAuthentication` and `PasswordAuthentication` allows to do what you want, i.e. for those users who present a public key, their access will be passwordless (provided their public key exists in the `authorized_keys` file); and those who don't, will be prompted for a password.

And `RSAAuthentication` is used only with version 1 of the protocol, which, hopefully, you are not using, as it is insecure.

Don't forget to read the `SSHD_CONFIG(5)` manpage.